# CakePhp model relationships not providing reverse references

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

currently my model relation ships are set up in the following fashion

```
class Post extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Post';
    var $displayField = 'title';
    var $hasMany = array('Comment');
    var $belongsTo = array('User');
 }

 class User extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'User';
    var $displayField = 'username';
    var $hasMany = array('Post', 'Comment');
 }

 class Comment extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Comment';
    var $displayField = 'id';
    var $belongsTo = array('User', 'Post');
 }
```

when i am trying to refer to the username in the comments section on my posts view 
it errors out saying invalid index and upon further inestigation i have noticed that my model is not including the user info as a back reference for my comments only the user information is being included for the posts

the resulting array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [Post] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => test post
            [user_id] => 1
            [body] => this is a test post 
            [date_posted] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [url_slug] => this-is-a-test-post
        )

    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [username] => admin
            [password] => e7b9f7bc09beee85947ef987d7df49df136c7c38
            [first_name] => Chris
            [last_name] => McGrath
            [roles] => Admin
            [email] => admin@thissite.com
            [last_login] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [member_since] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [FacebookProfile] => 
            [TwitterUserName] => 
        )

    [Comment] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [post_id] => 1
                    [user_id] => 1  //expecting this to pull user model for each 
                    [comment] => test comment
                )

        )

)
```

my question is is this being caused by something i am doing incorrectly in the model associations, is this a limitation of the model framework or should i be grabbing  user manually from the user model in this type of instance

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to grab the User from the Comment model?

Comment: no i want the user name and some of the other information for building jquery tooltips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing something like this:

```
$this->Post->recursive = 2; //This will get all the comments and their relationships
$post = $this->Post->read(null,$post_id); //The way you were getting your post.
debug($post); // You will see what it gets
```

**EDIT:**
You can try this too:

```
$this->Post->Comment->recursive = 2;
```

Comment: so should i be defining this in my controller or in my model ?

Comment: In your controller. Before render the view. Probably you're in the "view" action. You've a "view" function, in your PostController that is setting a $post to the posts/view.ctp view. So, somewhere in your view() function (in the controller) you've a line that fetches the Post you want to show (must be a read, somewhere). Immediately before the read, you should put "$this->Post->recursive = 2"

Answer (score 0):

using recursive = 2 is never a good idea.

```
$this->Post->find(
    'first',
    array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Post.id' => $id
        ),
        'contain' => array(
            'User',
            'Comment' => array(
                'User' => array(
                    'fields' => array(
                        'User.id',
                        'User.name'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable

Comment: @dogmatic96 He's a beginner. And in this case i think there's no problem. Everything fetched is going to be used.